# How do I set the admin favicon?

Tags: magento2, admin, favicons

How do I change the favicon that displays while in the Magento 2 admin? It currently displays the favicon for the base website, but I would like it to display a custom favicon (and not the Magento logo).

To be clear, I want a different favicon in the frontend from the backend admin.

I'd prefer a way via the admin, but can edit code if necessary.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if your question not solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to changes then you need to create an admin Theme.

First at `app/design/adminhtml` directory create a new `<Vendor>/<admin_theme>` directory.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html